# Missing Endpoint Key in QnA Maker

Tags: azure, azure-qna-maker

I had initially created a QNA maker but it failed so I removed it, and when attempted to re-create it, it is missing the endpoint key.

Answer (score 0):

Hard to know exactly what your problem is without further details. If you can see the KB at qnamaker.ai, click on the View Code button. That will give you the KB ID in the POST line, the Host, and the EndpointKey. There is also a separate set of keys within the Cognitive Service blade on the Azure Portal (I've not used those for anything, always the ones shown at qnamaker.ai). If this doesn't solve your issue, please provide additional context and I will try to assist.

[image]

Comment: I can't set up the KB or View Code button. When I deleted the failed QnA maker deployment I believe that had caused the Endpoint Key to be missing. I can't set up another QnA maker due to hitting the quota limit. I have created a web app bot but not it's linked to a KB or showing up as an Azure QnA service. Is there a workaround?

Comment: So you deleted the resource/Cognitive Service from Azure portal? Which quota have you hit?

Comment: When I was trying to create the a QnA service for a KB, the deployment failed. Not sure why it did. I made the mistake of deleting the deployment which caused the EndPoint key to be missing. Is there a way to restore it? I have the free Azure subscription. If I try to create another QnA service, it gives me the "Operation would exceed 'free' tier' service quota. You are using 1 out of 1 'free'tier service quota..."

Comment: It sounds like you may have deleted only part of the service. There is a QnA Resource and a Azure Search Service Resource that are both required. If you only deleted one, you may be hitting your quota on the other. Go to All Resources and check and see if you still have any resources with your app name.